# Override USB driver PID/VID

Tags: windows, usb, drivers

In Windows is there a way to load a USB driver and force it to use a different VID/PID? I'd like to test a device with a different driver, with out having to go back and change the VID/PID on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed an appropriate INF file for the driver and the only problem is that it specifies a different VID and PID from the actual USB device you want to use, this answer should work for you.  It is based on Microsoft's [instructions for installing  WinUSB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283(v=vs.85).aspx#installing_winusb_by_specifying__the_system-provided_device_class), which present as one option.

1. Connect your device to the computer via USB.
2. In the Device Manager, find the device.
3. Right-click the device and select "Update driver software...".
4. In the wizard, select "Browse my computer for driver software".
5. Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer".
6. Find your driver in that interface and select it.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this later this afternoon.